# HTML5 video tag doesnt display video

Tags: video, html, html5-video

I am trying to play a simple video in chrome 7.0.517.14 the code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>alykhantejani.com</title>
</head>

<body>
<video  width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>

</html>
```

The page is stored in the same folder as the movie.mp4.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`<video controls="controls" width="320" height="240" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>`

Try that

Comment: same result  - no video is loaded I see the control panel but no video is loading

Comment: try using JWplayer 

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-html5

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure your server supports the proper MIME types to deliver the video. Create an .htaccess file and add the following lines (for all manner of HTML5 video):

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/webm .webm
```

If that doesn't work, then it's a video encoding issue.